# WPF Resizable Canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, resize

I need to implement a `Canvas` which scales its contents according to its size. I know there is `Viewbox`, which scales everything inside of it. However I cannot use that, because some elements have a fixed size and cannot be scaled.

Also how can I bind the size of the `Canvas` to the parent element (for example a resizable window). There is sizeToContent for windows, I want the size fitting exactly the other way round. Also the canvas uses some drawing based on the size of the hosting element, how is redraw triggered and how can I ensure that it only draws if it gets a valid (or min) size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify any width or height to the canvas it automatically uses all the available space. This is because the default `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` are set to `Stretch`.

What do you mean by canvas that scales it's contents according to it's size without scaling all the contents as some have fixed size?

**Update after comments**

If your drawing algorithm already scales the content to the canvas' height and width then all you need to do is to resize the canvas to fit the area I believe? In that case just remove the hardcoded height/width values and the canvas will resize to fit the container.

You might need to use ActualHeight/ActualWidth instead of Height/Width in the drawing algorithm after this though. ActualHeight/ActualWidth return the values that the layout container will give your canvas so these represents the values the canvas is drawn with.

Comment: Well there is some drawing in the canvas, the drawing algo uses the height and with property of the canvas as a constant and things are drawn (or stretched) relative to this

Comment: If I set everything to stretch, Height and With of the canvas are not defined.. I guess I need to catch this in the code?

Comment: If I set everything to Strech, Height and With of the canvas are not defined when drawing first.. guess I need to catch this in the code

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect this. You can use ActualHeight and ActualWidth properties to find out the REAL height and width of the canvas.

Comment: I think ActualHeight/ActualWidth is what I need, however when drawing it's first set to 0, instead of Height/Width which are set to NaN.

I also need to to redraw everything once ActualHeight/-Width changes, how can I do that?

Comment: @Nils, there's a SizeChanged event you could react to.

Comment: aha, I was trying to attach it to CompositionTarget.Rendering

Answer (score 2):

I think you can find the answers to all your questions in my [London Underground demo](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2008/08/london-underground-wpf-demo.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this from memory, but if I recall correctly a Window uses either a Panel or a Canvas as part of it's ControlTemplate (in which lies the ContentPresenter), which means that a Canvas placed directly in a Window will have issues resizing automatically like it might elsewhere.  There are a few basic ways to address this.

1 Write a new ControlTemplate for your Window to use. :(
2 Place your content directly in the Window rather than in a Canvas inside the Window. :/
3 Do a by-name binding. :)

```
<MyWindow x:Name="topWindow">
    <Canvas x:Name="topCanvas" Width="{Binding ElementName=topWindow, Path=ActualWidth}" Height="{Binding ElementName=topWindow, Path=ActualHeight}">
        ...Content...
    </Canvas>
</MyWindow>
```

(As it happens, I often bind grids inside Canvases in this fashion, so I can easily animate items moving from one grid position to another.)